# Python strip only single specific characters from text/json

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm currently trying to scrape data from a website and want to automatically save them. I want to format the data before so I can use them as cvs or similar. The json is:

`{"counts":{"default":"27","quick_mode1":"48","quick_mode2":"13","custom":"281","quick_mode3":"0","total":369}}`

My code is:

```
x = '{"counts":{"default":"27","quick_mode1":"48","quick_mode2":"13","custom":"281","quick_mode3":"0","total":369}}'

y = json.loads(x)

print(y["total"])
```

But due to the `{"counts":` on the beginning and the corresponding  `}` on the end I can't just use it as a normal json file because the formatting breaks and it just puts an error message out (`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`), when I remove the characters manually it then works again.

How can I get rid of only those 2 parts?

Comment: What `{"counts":` are you talking about? The JSON you gave us is valid.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
The `{counts":` to reference does not exist elsewhere in your post.  We cannot debug code you haven't provided, nor can we diagnose only *part* of an error report.

Comment: OK, now you have `"counts"`, but the JSON is still valid. Please [edit] your post to show a full [mre], and include the **full text** of the traceback.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I had something wrong and updated it now, the first `players` was meant to say `counts`. Also added my current code of it.

Comment: So you access `"total"` like this: `print(y["counts"]["total"])`.

Answer (score -2):

I think that `json` library should go along with this, but if it really is an issue you can't get rid of, you could remove all occurrences of `{` and `}` characters in the string you are are receiving with `.replace()` function.

This requires chaining for every character you want to remove and is rather not an optimal solution, but as far as the strings you are processing are not long and/or you are not concerned about efficiency this should do just fine.

Example:

```
my_var.replace('{', '').replace('}', '')
```

Comment: No, that's a terrible idea. It will produce bad JSON if you do that.